# Title in address bar displaying twice

Tags: 8

I am having an issue that I don't know how to fix. The title of my website/pages are displayed twice and I can't figure out why. I configured my title at Configuration > basic site settings > name of website

[image]

Can anyone help me find what is causing this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check your site name. is it same as your node name or not?
 (admin/config/system/site-information)

Comment: Could be because of another module rewriting the page title. Are you using [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) or something?

Comment: How you configured title?

Comment: My site name says Testsite, my standard frontpage is http://localhost/testsite/node. But thats correct right ?

I am not using metatag.
How I configured my title is in my post.

Comment: When I remove the /node from standard frontpage, it says log in | Testsite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Drupal Title system works.

You **PageTitle| Sitename**

If you wants any modification then you can install [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) and [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) Module.